# if Drop object in Place and it will Create an Event

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

```
public GameObject CloseCloset;
public GameObject OpenCloset;
public GameObject Key;
OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{

  if (key. *position?* or * OverThe CloseCloset?*)
  {
      CloseCloset.setActive(false);
      OpenCloset.setActive(true); 
  }
}
```

I dont know how to set it. This is my last problem for my game (thesis). I Have this object(Key) and another 2 object (Open and Close Closet),

I want is when i drag my item(Key) ove to CloseCloset, the CloseCloset will disappear and the Open Closet will appear. Its like Close CLoset have a lock and when i drag the key it will create an event that the close closet will going to Open. I hope i can get an answer sooner or later.

By the way. All of them are Image, and key is the only having a **BUTTON** component

And this game that im creating is like the game **CUBE ESCAPE**

Comment: Which gameObject has this script?

Comment: The key, because it is the object that i will drop on close closet

Comment: The code you posted. Are you able to drag the key with it?

Comment: Yes i am able to drag it, the only thing that i need to solve iis the **IF STATEMENT**

Comment: Are these objects (key, OpenCloset, ClosedCloset) UI Elements or 3D objects?

Comment: They are all 2D, Yeah UI, im trying to create a game like **Cube Escape**.

Comment: Is this all the code you have in the script or is there more that can help understand the problem?

Comment: If you look at **Cube Escape** i know you can understand. This is all the code that i have. except the OnBeginDrag and OnDrag 

 Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to build your closet like this:

Create an empty gameobject ("Closet") and make both, the locked and the open models, a child of this. Disable the open model.

Then have the "Closet" handle the drop and compare gameobjects (store a reference to the key as field and compare that to the gameobject that gets dropped). If they are the same, disable the locked model and enable the open model.

You could also use tags to compare the object, but that might get cluttered when you have a lot of keys and closets that don't share keys.

Edit:
You can use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDropHandler.html to handle the drop.